# Clunky transition with jQuery animate and server loading latency - ways to improve?

Tags: jquery, css

I've got a preview tool that - when the user selects an orientation, re-lays out the screen to have a wider (landscape) or higher (portrait) preview window containing a generated image.

What I would like to happen is..

- User selects a new orientation (say Landscape)
- They see a loading gif for say 500ms
- Whilst they see a loading gif, the preview window resizes to the correct dimensions
- Then the new generated image appears in the preview panel

Here are two snippets from a PrintPreviewer object which are at the heart of the issue, updatePreview() and resizePreviewWindow().

The problem is that both of these functions were trying to use the css() method to insert a new background-image into the #preview area. When I tried to add a loading gif to the step in resizePreviewWindow(), unfortunately, the loader gif was never shown. So instead, I have now opted below to simply remove the preview background image temporarily. I need to do this, because if the old bg image remained in the preview panel whilst the new (correctly ratio'd) image was generated, it looks very odd for about 200ms as the resizePreviewWindow() function does its work.

A) This already feels rather clunky as a way to switch orientations for the user. Although this works, I feel it could do with some tidying up and DRYing out, and would appreciate some guidance.

B) I was hoping that I'd be able to use a loading gif in the time it takes updatePreview() to point to the server at /prints/preview? and display in the preview panel whilst the new generated image is fetched and streamed into place.

```
var PrintPreviewer = {

    init: function () {
        var data = this.cleanForm();

        this.updatePreview(data);
        this.selectBoxUpdate();
        this.changeColor();
        this.changeTextarea();
        this.changeStyle();
    },

    // removed some code for clarity

    updatePreview: function (data) {
        var preview = $('#preview')
        preview.fadeIn('slow', function() {
            preview.attr('preview-preface', '');
            preview.css("background-image","url('/prints/preview?"+data+"')");
            console.log(data);
        });
    },

    //removed some code for clarity

    resizePreviewWindow: function (elem) {
    // when user selects new orientation put correct shape window
    var prevSurr = $('#previewSurround');
    var prev = $('#preview');

    switch (elem.val()) 
    {
    case 'landscape':
        prevSurr.removeClass("portrait square").addClass("landscape");
        prev
            .css({
            "background-image": "none",
            })
            .animate({
            height: "380px",
        }, 100); 
        break;
    case 'portrait':
        prevSurr.removeClass("landscape square").addClass("portrait");
        prev
            .css({
            "background-image": "none",
            })
            .animate({
            height: "540px",
        }, 100); 
        break;
    case 'square':
        prevSurr.removeClass("portrait landscape").addClass("square");
        prev
            .css({
            "background-image": "none",
            })
            .animate({
            height: "420px",
        }, 100); 
        break;
    default:
        console.log("hi");
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out *some* of my issues, but I reckon I've done it in a relatively roundabout way. I didn't want to use the `$.ajax()` method, but resorted to in the end to get the desired effect. However, I can only get the loading GIF to work on page load - never when the user has initiated the updatePreview() function themselves. Still looking for a solid answer to why this would be.

```
    var PrintPreviewer = {

    init: function () {
        var data = this.cleanForm();
        this.updatePreview(data);
    },

    updatePreview: function (data) {

        var preview = $('#preview')
        var url = "/prints/preview?"+data

        PrintPreviewer.loadContent(url);

    },

    loadContent: function(href) {

      $.ajax({
        url: href,
        success: function (data) {
          $("#preview")
                        .css("background-image","url('"+href+"')")
                        .attr('preview-preface', '');
        }
      });
      },


        // removed code for brevity

    resizePreviewWindow: function (elem) {
        // when user selects new orientation put correct shape window
        var prevSurr = $('#previewSurround');
        var prev = $('#preview');

        switch (elem.val()) 
        {
        case 'landscape':
            prevSurr.removeClass("portrait square").addClass("landscape");
            prev
                .css({
                "background-image": "none",
                })
                .animate({
                height: "380px",
            }, 100); 
            break;
        case 'portrait':
            prevSurr.removeClass("landscape square").addClass("portrait");
            prev
                .css({
                "background-image": "none",
                })
                .animate({
                height: "540px",
            }, 100); 
            break;
        case 'square':
            prevSurr.removeClass("portrait landscape").addClass("square");
            prev
                .css({
                "background-image": "none",
                })
                .animate({
                height: "420px",
            }, 100); 
            break;
        default:
            console.log("hi");
        }
    }

}

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#preview').ajaxStart(function(){
       $(this).addClass("loading").attr('preview-preface', '');
    });

    $('#preview').ajaxComplete(function(){
       $(this).removeClass("loading");
    });

});
```